# Proving sequence converges to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following question:

> Let $f \in \operatorname{RS}_a^b (\alpha)$, that is, the function $f$
>   is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable over the interval $[a,b]$ with respect
>   to $\alpha = \alpha(x)$, and let $\alpha$ be continuous. Prove that
>   $$\left\{ \int_a^{b-\frac{1}{n}} f(x) d\alpha(x) \right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \to \int_a^{b} f(x) d\alpha(x)$$

What I tried to do was to consider an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and show that
$$\left| \int_a^{b-\frac{1}{n}} f d\alpha-\int_a^{b} f d\alpha\right|=\left| - \int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^b f d\alpha\right|=\left|  \int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^b f d\alpha\right|< \epsilon$$
Now, intuitively this last term tends to zero as $n \to \infty$, so we could always pick a big enough $n$ to make it smaller than $\epsilon$. How can I argue this formally?  Is this the correct way to proceed? I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is bounded and $\alpha$ is (uniformly) continuous.

Comment: @Matematleta how do we know that $f$ is bounded? Wouldn't we need it to be continuous to say that?

Comment: It's part of the definition of the R-S integral that $f$ be bounded, right?

Comment: Boundedness is not just part of the definition, it is a necessary condition for RS integrability.

Comment: @Matematleta So, assuming we can say that $f$ is bounded (say by $K$) then $$\left|  \int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^b f d\alpha\right| \leq \left| K \int_{b-\frac{1}{n}}^b  d\alpha\right| $$
and then writing it as a sum over a partition we get 
$$|K \sum_P \Delta \alpha_i| = |K(\alpha(b)-\alpha(b-\frac{1}{n}))|$$
which can be made as small as we want by the uniform continuity of $\alpha$. Does this look right to you?

Comment: @ThomasBladt: That's fine as long as $\alpha$ is monotone.

Comment: @RRL indeed,  and that is what I meant.

Comment: Ok, thank you to both :)

Comment: It is not yet clear how to prove this if $\alpha$ has unbounded variation.  There are such functions that are also continuous on compact intervals.  But it is rare for the RS integral to exist unless for example $f$ is constant.